# Eloquent Order by

Tags: laravel-5, orm, model, eloquent, slim

i have code to call data in eloquent like this :

```
$args['orderby'] = array('id','asc');
$orderby  = (string) str_replace('"',"'", str_replace(']','',str_replace('[','',json_encode($args['orderby']))));
//Result $orderby = 'id','asc'
```

i put the variable **orderby** in method orderby eloquent but this is not work for me

```
Table::select($args['value'])->where($coloumn_search, 'ilike', '%'.$search.'%')->orderBy($orderby)->get();
```

if i put **'id','asc'** in method orderby eloquent this work for me

```
Table::select($args['value'])->where($coloumn_search, 'ilike', '%'.$search.'%')->orderBy('id','asc')->get();
```

what difference '**id','asc'** and **variabel orderby** which I have create ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two completely different things:

- `->orderBy($orderby)`: one array parameter
- `->orderBy('id','asc')`: two string parameters

You can use an array like this:

```
->orderBy(...$orderby)
```